# Circuit for USB OTG

Tags: usb, otg

I made up the following schematic, it is intended for devices that do not support OTG.

Is it adequate for the job?

[image: schematic]

Comment: You need to connect the ground, and you need to convince the software to put the SoC's USB into host mode and interact with a peripheral.  For phones not intended to be hosts that may require rooting or a custom OS build.  Leveraging that latent capability may be hard - but it's questionable if there have been *any* smart phone SoCs that did not actually have it in silicon.

Comment: @ChrisStratton  I'm interested in learning where to read up on altering the kernel code. I have an RCA Voyager tablet and attempting to have it permanently connected to a power supply and act as a USB host to a GPIO module at the same time using the OTG wiring scheme. With my tests I can so far either host the GPIO module with pins 4 & 5 connected, but not charge the tablet - or I can charge the tablet by disconnecting pin 4, but then can't communicate with the GPIO module.

Comment: @Snadford - that is a different question than the one on this page, and it is also an off topic "usage" question.  You can ask around on XDA developers or places like that.  Let's both delete these comments later today to keep things here on point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No** that will not "work". By "work" I mean: being able to use the flash drive from the phone.

Your "solution" only provides 5 V to the flash drive. It does not convert the phone's USB port into a "host" port which would be needed for this to work.

There is more needed than just a 5 V supply to get USB OTG functionality. The USB port on the phone needs to be designed for OTG. If it is not, **forget** about OTG on that phone.

Comment: Very few phone SoCs in the modern era have not had the fundamental capability to operate in the host role, quite possible none.  In your hurry to guess at something that may well not be an issue, you overlooked the lack of a ground.

Comment: @ChrisStratton The lack of the ground connection is **irrelevant** when the phone **does not support OTG** as stated by OP. Even though the SoC might support OTG doesn't mean that the phone does. The phone manufacturer might simply have switched OTG off because they do not want to support it. There is no reason to assume that OP is trying this with a "modern" phone. If you have a better answer then write one instead of complaining about mine.

Comment: Engineers think through problems, they don't merely shout and bully in gnorance.  Having been involved in several successful efforts to do this, this is probably achievable if they can alter the kernel code.  The hardware isn't really the impediment you imagine in your unfamiliarity.  The latent capability isn't something you "switch off" it is something the software support for which would have been omitted in a stock build, but is still there if a custom one can be run.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Fair enough, then write down how that's done in an Answer, list the phones which apply and stop complaining about my answer. OP asked if his circuit / adapter would do the trick, I think it will not. You disagree, fine, then share how it is done.

Comment: What you still have not realized that is virtually *all* smartphone SoCs over the past decade have supported this - the original Android models were the classic example of engine support but no VBus charge pump.  The short list would be those that don't have support for host mode - and I cannot think of a single entry to put on it.  Can you name a specific smartphone SoC with a USB engine that is *not* capable of being a host???     Feature phone SoCs might not, but that does not seem to be what the question is about.